# Reverse voltage in LED buck converter circuit

Tags: voltage, led, buck

The circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foixjb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Everything is fine except when the switch is open, I measure ~-3.5V on the points marked.

Why is that and is it dangerous for other components that get powered by the 5V after the switch?

The module is of those which are all over ebay

[image]

Comment: Please add a link to the datasheet and check if there is a specification on minimum loading.

Comment: When you measure -3.5 V on GND, what are you measuring relative to? Where did you put the black lead of the multimeter?

Comment: @Transistor well I got it off ebay so good luck finding that. It's likely not the case because if I remove the diode from the schematic the voltage disappears.

Comment: @ThePhoton my bad, fixed it. When switch is closed I measure 5V when open -3.5V

Comment: The LM2586 chip can be used as a flyback converter (Texas Instruments) and may be "inside" the thing you bought from ebay (or not) but, without decent product details this question is as good as closed.

Comment: The LM2586 is a step-up converter IC and it has 7 pin, not 4 like in your schematic. *I measure ~-3.5V on the points marked.* I do not see any "marked points". *is it dangerous for other components that get powered by the 5V after the switch?* Think about what you ask, you ask if something that is normally powered from 5 V can get damaged from **a lower voltage**.

Comment: Hint: disconnect the LED and measure again.

Comment: 1. Are  you sure it's not actually an LM2576?  2. Is there an earth connection on the 12V supply? Or is it some random wall-plug adapter with two pins? If the latter, try plugging it in backwards (the mains pins, not the output pins), if that's possible.

Comment: It "fixed" the schematic again, it was a typo, it's an LM2596 and it's a board I'm not using the IC directly. @Bimpelrekkie it's a lower *reversed* voltage, which is not good. And I also did try to disconnect the LED, the reverse voltage is not present then.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the 12V im getting off of an old PC power supply.

Comment: @php_nub_qq 1. Are you sure it's not actually an LM2576? 2. Is there an earth connection on the 12V supply?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I attached an image of the board, I thought it was pretty common. The PSU is standard unmodified 350W supply of which I'm using the MOLEX connectors. I believe everything is in tact.

Comment: Okay, so it's not an LM2586. Do you have the earth connection to the PSU (that's the mains cord) going to a 3-pin plug in the wall?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany um well yes but the wall socket is not grounded physically, how is that relevant? It is kind of a weird setup, the socket was originally intended for lights only so there is a 2 wire cable going to the panel, which is what I mean by the socket is not grounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PC power supply is not earthed (it should be, for noise and for safety), that means that there is voltage relative to earth on both outputs. Since the LM2596 module is connected to the PSU those outputs are waving around at tens of volts wrt earth.

Stray capacitance from the output and multimeter leads couples to the LED ground connection and it is rectified by the diode (LED), so you see a DC voltage there (at very little available current)

If you properly earth the PSU that effect will disappear.

Comment: Since it would be quite hard to ground the outlet properly (long distance to panel), would connecting the ground to neutral suffice?

Comment: Highly unsafe. Just ignore it. But the power supply should be earthed for safety.

Comment: I'm just worried because in parallel I have a raspberry pi and recently my SD card got corrupted. I was suspecting exactly this negative voltage but as you explain things now it seems like it would disappear as soon as some kind of load is connected if I understand correctly, not sure if it's enough to do such damage.

Comment: Probably not, RPi can trash the SD card by improper shutdown/power cycling, but for safety you should earth the power supply.